# Aligning controls to appear horizontally centered on screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to align an image view so that it appears in the center of the screen, and then two buttons that appear centered below the image view.

However, I can't get it to work. I've tried many different ideas, but none of them work.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Thanks!

Here is a screenshot of what is going on:

[image]

And here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="?android:attr/colorForeground"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSurf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="500px"
        android:maxWidth="500px"
        android:minHeight="500px"
        android:minWidth="500px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use constraintLayout always when you have complex layout

Comment: @PavelPoley it's actually wrapped in a constraintLayout. It wasn't showing up originally in my post because I didn't format it correctly. It should be visible now.  Thanks!

Comment: So why you need LinearLayout inside constraintLayout? it is really unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code, but you should work with `ConstraintLayout` directly, without nested layouts. Also you should use `dp` instead `px`.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:background="?android:attr/colorForeground"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgSurf"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:maxHeight="500px"
                android:maxWidth="500px"
                android:minHeight="500px"
                android:minWidth="500px" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Stop"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Check this video about 
[ConstraintLayout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzmB3UxxhaA)